# iOS 11.0 UITextField secureTextEntry incorrect display?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios11

iOS 11 makes this strange effect when turning on / off secure text entry.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I solved it, it was a super.drawText inside the draw delegate, a my mistake :(

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are all of your text settings? Does it happen in the simulator, real device? I've seen similar behavior in the Xcode 9 Watch Simulator, but it doesn't occur on a real device.

Comment: I solved it, thanks @MattH

Comment: You should delete this question.

Comment: @maddy I want leave the question for others, it is a useful information why Swift suggests super.drawText as the first choice instead of super.draw